# Is USB 2.0 Shield Wiring Necessary For a Power Only Connection? (Power Supply to Raspberry Pi)

Tags: power-supply, usb, raspberry-pi, grounding, dac

**I am building a low ripple power supply for my Raspberry Pi Zero 2W + DAC combo.**

The output of my power supply will be a female USB A 2.0 connector, using a regular USB A to Micro B cable to power my Raspberry Pi. Note, none of the USB data lines will be used!

**My goal is to give the Raspberry Pi + DAC the cleanest, least noisy power possible.**

While building the power supply, I wondering what to do with the USB shield wire inside the power supply. I have found that the USB shield wire is connected to the PCB ground on the Raspberry Pi side, but researching this topic for the power supply side gives very mixed and *numerous* results.

**Based on what I have researched, the USB shield wiring options are:**

- **Leave the USB shield wire unconnected in the power supply.** Some suggest this might introduce EMI like an antenna, adding interference on the power line.
- **Connect the UBS shield wire to the power supply DC ground.** Some suggest this might cause a ground loop or 0v reference problem, possibly causing multiple issues. (Audio + Ground Loop = Bad)
- **Connect the USB shield wire to the power supply DC ground via a resistor/capacitor combo.** Even though this is shown in many USB recommendations, some suggest this is a very bad idea, for a variety of reasons. (Didn't really understand most of them.)
- **Connect the USB shield wire to the power supply metal case enclosure, close to the USB plug.** Some suggested this might be a bad idea as a metal case for a PSU would be connected to the mains ground connection, and if for some reason something was wired wrong someplace, this could cause catastrophe.

After reading many, many informational sites on the web, even a few here on StackExchange, I am no closer to knowing what is best in my situation; Power Supply to Pi with power only (no data lines used.) I would like to know which one of these options (or possibly one I haven't found yet) would be the best for my situation. My goal is to give the Raspberry Pi + DAC the cleanest, least noisy power possible, and I want to make sure my 'power' USB connection in this scenario is correct.

**Any advice, comments, criticism, or feedback on how I should wire the USB shield wire within my power supply would be greatly appreciated!**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, frankly, it might not matter in any way for the sound quality, depending on how your power supply works, and how the DAC connects to RPi itself. So for completeteness, provide the power supply schematics, and how these boards are wired.

Comment: The rectifier/regulator board is pre-made. I don't have the schematic for it. It's called a "STUDER900". I purchased it for its claim for low noise for devices like DACs. I am using a toroidal transformer to feed this board, plus fuses, in a metal case. Also, I am using an Allo MiniBoss DAC with the Raspberry Pi Zero 2W. The MiniBoss has no 'output' pin header or alternate power supply connection.

Comment: Yeah but will there be earthed mains inlet in your metal box for power supply? Will you connect mains inlet earth to metal chassis? Will the 5VDC be floating or earth referenced? See, a ground loop between USB connectors through USB cable is not an issue you should be worried about, it's the potential ground loops through the device connections, including the amplifier you will connect this DAC, and the other devices connected to amplifier, and how the amp and other devices are earthed, or left floating. Your system starts from the mains wiring, e.g. a power strip. Focus on safety, not sound.

Comment: Agreed, safety is really first priority. The mains ground will be connected to the metal case of the power supply, leaving the power supply DC ground floating(?)

Comment: Yes, and if you do connect mains earth to USB connector shield, only plugging in the USB cable to RPi will connect mains earth to DC ground. If the USB cable has a shield, and if it is connected on both ends.

Comment: Not sure I like the idea of the mains earth connected to the DC ground of the Pi. Unless there’s another suggestion, I’m just going to leave the shield wire unconnected. Seems to be the safest course of action.

Comment: But it might already be connected on the power supply PCB. Do you have schematics of what you bought, or any manual or document that tells how it works? Have you measured it? It may have links from mounting screw holes to DC ground. It may be designed to be connected to earthed metal chassis, snd leaving it insulated so it floats may cause more problems. So that's two completely sepatate things, you must know how to build the supply as it is intended, and then when you know it, how to best wire up the connector of your choise. The shield connection is less important than the big picture.

Comment: Agreed. Thank you for your advice.